# How can i check if what I input into my text based calculator is an number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, project, calculator

When I prompt the console to ask the user to input a number for the calculator, I want to check if what the user input is a number. In the first_input() I used a if else condition to check if what the user input was a number. Although if false the function is called again to prompt the user to type a number, it returns none once i try calculating it into my calculator, why is this and how can I properly return the number properly after the user fails to input a number?

```
# Operations variable
oper = "+-*/"

# Calculates basic operations
def calc(x, op, y):
    for i in oper:
        if i == str(op):
            return eval(str(x) + op + str(y))

# Main function that controls the text-based calculator
def console_calculator():
    def first_input():
        x = input('Type your first number: ')
        if x.isnumeric():
            return x
        else:
            print('Please type in a number')
            first_input()

    def operation_input():
        operat = input('Type one of the following, "+ - * /": ')
        return operat 

    def next_input():
        y = input('Type your next number: ')
        return y

    answer = calc(first_input(), operation_input(), next_input())
    print(answer)

console_calculator()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest a try/except block. This way it will return the integer itself especially since you're already turning them into strings in the eval block.

```
x = input('Type your first number: ')
try:
    return int(x)
except ValueError:
    print('Please type in a number')
    ...
```

Also to keep asking the user for an integer until they input the correct value I'd use a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two functions for user input you can use single function call it two times. and you also need to add `return` before function call in user input.

```
def console_calculator():
    def user_input():
        x = input('Type your number: ')
        if x.isnumeric():
            return x
        else:
            print('Please type in a number')
            return user_input()

    def operation_input():
        operat = input('Type one of the following, "+ - * /": ')
        return operat 


    answer = calc(user_input(), operation_input(), user_input())
    print(answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually hid the answer in your own question:

> how can I properly return the number

You forgot to `return` in your else branch:

```
# Calculates basic operations
def calc(x, op, y):
    for i in op:
        if i == str(op):
            return eval(str(x) + op + str(y))

# Main function that controls the text-based calculator
def console_calculator():
    def first_input():
        x = input('Type your first number: ')
        if x.isnumeric():
            return x
        else:
            print('Please type in a number')
            return first_input() # missing return

    def operation_input():
        operat = input('Type one of the following, "+ - * /": ')
        return operat 

    def next_input():
        y = input('Type your next number: ')
        return y

    answer = calc(first_input(), operation_input(), next_input())
    print(answer)

console_calculator()
```

But you also have a compilation error because you refer to `oper` but the parameter is called `op`.

This merely answers your question, but doesn't address the architecture (which others will, as they cover better implementations).